# .NET Core 3 ClaimTypes.Name returning Object Null Reference Error

Tags: asp.net-core

Using .NET Core 3, I set my JWT token's like this:

```
// generate token that is valid for 7 days
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]);
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
   Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
   {
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
   }),
   Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
   SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
   };
  var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
  var loggedInUser = _mapper.Map<AuthUserDto>(user);

  // return OK and the bearer JWT token to client if successfully created
  return Ok(new
  {
     token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
     expiration = token.ValidTo,
     loggedInUser
   });
```

The JWT tokens are being stored in local storage and in my Angular 8 service, I am passing getting the bearer token from storage and sending it along with my service to the api like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
  })
};



 getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    console.log(httpOptions)
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl, httpOptions);
  }
```

In my api controller, I have a get method which accepts anonymous and returns a list of objects. However, I need to check each object and see if it was an anonymous user who asked for the list or a user who was logged in, that I way I can hide/show things on the UI as appropriate. However my `GetUserIdFromToken()` function is throwing an Object Not Set to Instance of an Object Null Reference error.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetSubmissionCallsRoute")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SubmissionCall), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSubmissionCalls()
{
   IEnumerable<SubmissionCall> calls;
   calls = await _subCallsRepo.GetSubmissionCallsAsync();

   var callsToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SubmissionCallListDto>>(calls);

   foreach (var returndto in callsToReturn)
   {
      var IdFromToken = GetUserIdFromToken();
      if (IdFromToken == string.Empty)
      {
         returndto.RequestingUserIsResourceOwner = false;
       }

      returndto.RequestingUserIsResourceOwner = CompareUserIdToIdFromToken(returndto.UserId);
   }

  return Ok(callsToReturn);
}




#region COMMON
        private bool CompareUserIdToIdFromToken(string id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) throw new ArgumentNullException("User Id can't be null or empty");
            if (id != User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value) return false;
            return true;
        }

        private string GetUserIdFromToken()
        {
            return User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`[AllowAnonymous]` **bypasses all authorization statements** [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1). That means .NET Core won't call Authorization Middleware to validate JWT token itself, so there are nothing in `HttpContext.User` here. If you want to create one API that accepted both scenarios Anonymous and Authorized, you should write your custom `Middleware` of `Filter` to prevent these cases (by finding any `Authorization Header` in HTTP Request).